# How to add values from another DataFrame onto rows where a column matches?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a['id'] = range(0,100)
a['N'] = 100

b = pd.DataFrame()
b['id'] = 3*np.arange(0,100)
b['N'] = 50
```

What I want to do, is for rows in `a` where the `'id'` matches the `'id'` of a row in `b` to add `b['N']`. With a **very** inefficient and poorly-coded for-loop, that would be something like:

```
for idx in a[a.id.isin(b.id)].index:
    a.loc[idx, 'N'] = a.loc[idx, 'N'] + b.loc[b.id == a.loc[idx, 'id'], 'N'].iloc[0]
```

Is there a way to do the above, but with efficient DataFrame operations? For example, a better way might be to take only the rows in `a` and `b` that have matching `'id'`, sort them both by ascending (so that they are the same exact ids in the same order), and then just add the `'N'` column. This would require us to select the rows, sort them, add them, and finally concatenate back into the rows of `a` that didn't have matching `'id'` in `b`, but also seems inefficient. What is the recommended way of doing this in pandas/numpy

Comment: by add, do you mean sum? Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: So in this case it would be sum yes, but I think the question would be the same for other types of operations; i.e you want to perform some operation, based on the values of another dataframe, only in cases where some identifier in both dataframes matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "id" is unique, you can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and add the mapped values:

```
a['N'] = a['N'].add(a['id'].map(b.set_index('id')['N']), fill_value=0)

a
    id      N
0    0  150.0
1    1  100.0
2    2  100.0
3    3  150.0
4    4  100.0
..  ..    ...
95  95  100.0
96  96  150.0
97  97  100.0
98  98  100.0
99  99  150.0

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Oof. I like this answer because it's one-line and seems like the "direct" way to get there. But I need to figure out what's going on first; I haven't used map before. Is `b.set_index('id')['N']` acting as dictionary (id:N) that places each id in a with N if it's in the dictionary and 0 if not? I think I'll accept this one since it seems more direct, but both answers are good and the other seems easier to use without looking up.

Comment: @Marses I've added a link to the documentation, that has some useful examples. The idea of `map` is to map values in one domain to another based on the mapper argument passed to it (in this case, a Series). `a['id']` is mapped with `temp = b.set_index('id')['N']`, based on the index of `temp` the corresponding number in `temp` is "assigned" to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can simply do a `merge` and then `sum`:

```
a = a.merge(b,on="id",how="left")
a["result"] = a[["N_x","N_y"]].sum(1)

print (a)

    id  N_x   N_y  result
0    0  100  50.0   150.0
1    1  100   NaN   100.0
2    2  100   NaN   100.0
3    3  100  50.0   150.0
4    4  100   NaN   100.0
..  ..  ...   ...     ...
95  95  100   NaN   100.0
96  96  100  50.0   150.0
97  97  100   NaN   100.0
98  98  100   NaN   100.0
99  99  100  50.0   150.0
```

Comment: Ah it's always a merge. Both answers were good, to be honest. I think this one is actually easier to implement without looking up how to do the other one.